# XCTest UI Record and Play - Simulator not updating UI

Tags: xctest, ios9, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

Apple released a new UI Testing framework 2 days ago during WWDC2015. I'm trying to write a test case and when I try to record the UI testing, to generate the scaffolding code, it looks the code is being generated, however the UI on the simulator is not actually updating.

i.e When I tap on a button, the code is generated to actually find the button and tap, but the button is not actually tapped simultaneously on the simulator.
So basically I'm not able to go to the next screen on the simulator, to actually proceed in the test case.

The WWDC session video showed an example of an iPhone app (Lister app). But I'm trying it on a iPad 2 app. Thats about the only difference.

Any clues about why this might be happening?

Wanted to check if there has been other instances of these before actually filing a Radar with Apple.

Comment: I downloaded the Lister application by Apple which they used an example to test the new Framework. Looks like that is working on the iPad as well. 
The record and play works. 
However, in my app it doesn't simulate the UI as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue.

The problem was, in the "deployment target" section in the main Application target, there are different columns for all the targets listed.
For the Application's UI test target, the target was set to iOS8.
Changed it to iOS9 and it started working.